# Find Using a HasMany/BelongsTo Chain

Tags: grails, join

I'm trying to get a list of items from a chain of domain classes that are linked together via havingMany/belongsTo properties - here is an overview of the chain:

```
OrganisationShr  ---- (hasMany) ->  
     UserShr ---- (hasMany) -> 
     VideoShr ---- (hasMany) -> 
     PublishedShr
```

I want to get a list of all Published for an Organisation which is identified by the User that is logged in at the time.

To identify the Organisation I have to go up the chain from the current logged in user. Once the Organisation is found it a simple chain search to get the the list of Published.

But my problem is going up from the current logged-in user to get the organisation - here is the find code that I'm working with:

Having found the user from the session user name:

```
def usersId = UserShr.findByName(session.user.name)

returnValue = PublishedShr.findAll
{ 
    VideoShr.findAll{
            UserShr.findAll{OrganisationShr.findAll{idEq(UserShr.get(usersId))}}
    }
}
```

I have been trying various different approaches around this basic find structure.

I understand that I can set up a criteria condition to do this type of join. However the dynamic finder approach seems a simpler route to me - given my limited experience of these types of joins. Also the ability to put a join find together at any point seems powerful and flexible - I guess there must be some comeback doing this such as performance/ response? Happy to be pointed to a suitable web link to find out more on this of course.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Concerned portion of each domain class:

```
class OrganisationShr { 
    static hasMany = [userId: UserShr]

    static fetchMode = [userId: 'eager'] 
} 

class UserShr { 
    static belongsTo = [ organId: OrganisationShr] 
    static hasMany = [videoId: VideoShr]

    static fetchMode = [videoId: 'eager'] 
} 

class VideoShr { 
    static belongsTo = [ userId: UserShr] 
    static hasMany = [publId: PublishedShr] 

    static fetchMode = [publId: 'eager']
} 

class PublishedShr { 
    static belongsTo = [ videoId: VideoShr] 
}
```

Comment: If you show the source code for the 4 relevant domain classes that will help.  You don't need to show the whole thing, just the parts that express the relationships.

Comment: They are: class OrganisationShr { static hasMany = [userId: UserShr]
 static fetchMode = [userId: 'eager'] } and

Comment: They are: For Organisation: class OrganisationShr { static hasMany = [userId: UserShr]
  }   For Users: class UserShr {    static belongsTo = [ organId: OrganisationShr]     static hasMany = [videoId: VideoShr]}. For videos: class VideoShr {    static belongsTo = [ userId: UserShr]
   static hasMany = [publId: PublishedShr] } and finally for published: class PublishedShr { static belongsTo = [ videoId: VideoShr] }. Also all havingMany constraints have a fetch mode easy of the form:   static fetchMode = [publId: 'eager'].

Comment: Struggling with the formatting of the comment - They are: For Organisation: `class OrganisationShr { static hasMany = [userId: UserShr] }` For Users: `class UserShr { static belongsTo = [ organId: OrganisationShr] static hasMany = [videoId: VideoShr]}` For videos: `class VideoShr { static belongsTo = [ userId: UserShr] static hasMany = [publId: PublishedShr] }` and finally for published: `class PublishedShr { static belongsTo = [ videoId: VideoShr] }`. Also all havingMany constraints have a fetch mode easy of the form: ` static fetchMode = [publId: 'eager']`